# How to show web view in Xcode Empty Application without XIB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4, xcode4.2

There is probably already an answer for this somewhere, but I must not be searching for the right thing, so am asking here...

When I create a new project in Xcode 4.2.1 as an Empty Application, is it possible to show a web view without an Xib file?

There seem to be lots of answers for how to add an Xib to an Empty Application but I am wondering if it can be done without one. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alloc, init and add to window rootView

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    controller.view = view;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```